# Can't nail the problems with this code

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013

Ok so I got this thing going here. 
I keep getting a few errors.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdio>


//functions called
int get_lmt();
int get_total_trash();
void print_output(int, int);

//why is it void?
int main(void)
{

    char hauler[100];
    int t_trash=0, lmt=0;

    printf("Hello \n What is your name: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s", &hauler);

    t_trash = get_total_trash();
    lmt = get_lmt();

    printf("Name: %s\n", &hauler);
    print_output(lmt, t_trash);
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}




int get_total_trash()
{
    char yn = 'y';
    int t_trash = 0, trash=0;

    while (yn != 'n')
    {
        printf("What is your trash: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%i", &trash);

        t_trash = trash + t_trash;

        printf("Do you have more trash tons? (y or n): ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%c", &yn);
    }

    return t_trash;
}

int get_lmt()
{
    int lmt = 0;

    printf("What was last months trash: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%i", &lmt);

    return lmt;
}

void print_output(int lmt, int t_trash)
{
    float rate = 350.00, charge;
    int sum=0, total=0;

    if (lmt > t_trash)
    {

        printf("Total trash tons: %i\n", &t_trash);
        printf("Last month's trash: %i\n", &lmt);
        printf("Rate: $ %.2f\n", &rate);

    }

    else
    {
        printf("What is your tonnage rate: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%.2f\n", &charge);



        sum = t_trash - lmt;
        total = sum * charge;
        rate = rate + total;



        printf("Total trash tons: %i\n", &t_trash);
        printf("Last month's trash: %i\n", &lmt);
        printf("Rate: $ %.2f\n", &rate);

    }
}
```

Now what it should be doing is, The main should be calling the functions on screen as needed. 
Now i did all of this with cout cin and it works fine no problems. But when I run this (this is modified to the printf and scanf) it says:

OK UPDATE: Got a ton of it to work. Just one more thing and I should be good. The outcome will not go as expected.

Instead of an output of 
last months trash: 100 (asked at the end of the loop)
trash tonnage: 50 (accumulated in the loop)
rate: 350.00 (float variable)

(this is if last month trash was > this month.)

I get just bad numbers all around. It makes no mathematical sense. 
Other then that it works fine. 
Does the code the the last function look wrong to you guys?

Comment: Your `print_output` declaration does not match its definition.

Comment: omg are you kidding me.
that was the problem? 
Give me a min to check it

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behavior. @user3255517 no, he isn't.

Comment: fflush(stdin); is undefined? 
how would i fix that because i think this is killing me now. 
I got some of it working and now it is going nuts

Comment: *"I keep getting a few errors"*.  Would you like to tell us what the errors are???  Also, I cannot think of **anything** less descriptive than *"Can't nail the problems with this code.  Ok so I got this thing going here"*.  You should read [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: @abelenky actually the question has since changed from what the original title states. I did put the error code up before now the question is different but the title wasn't updated.
And my current problem is stated below the code.

Comment: You need to understand pointers, try: [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/)
Always check return values (e.g. from scanf perhaps)

Comment: i should be able to do this without pointers. That is next week i dive into that.

Comment: i did find out why the system is not accepting the variable the first time. It was the scanf("%c \n")
that \n was the one messing up the program. 
now on to the new part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of problems with this code. Lots of them.

1) print_output defintiion takes in a char[100] (char*), print_output declatation takes a char

2) When you pass hauler into print_output, you are passing in hauler[100] (a char, and one pass the end of the array to boot)

3) printf("Name: %s\n", &hauler); hauler is of type char[100] (char*), so &hauler is char**.

there is probably more.

Comment: well hauler is a string, if i have to i can kick that out of the code.
but how would i fix it? It just gives me an error message whenever i change it to hauler